# Vertically center text in PowerDot

Tags: vertical-alignment, powerdot

I'd like to center vertically all text in all my slide, in Powerdot.

I think  `\pddefinetemplate` could be used with options, but I can't find how.

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[style=aggie]{powerdot}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[francais]{babel} 
\begin{document}
\begin{wideslide}{Illustration}
I'd like to center vertically my text, in each slide. Thanks a lot
\end{wideslide}
\end{document}
```

Could someone help me ? Best regards,

Comment: Hi, surely we are all here to give you an answer but if you do not enter your LaTeX code along with the application we can not help you the best.

Comment: Hello, you're righ. Here is my code. Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs too many changes in the code ifr you want all slide types be vertically centered. It is easier if you coud use a command like `\Fill`:

```
\documentclass[style=aggie]{powerdot}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[francais]{babel} 
\newcommand\Fill{\vspace*{\fill}\null}

\begin{document}
\begin{wideslide}{Illustration}\Fill
I'd like to center vertically my text, in each slide. Thanks a lot
I'd like to center vertically my text, in each slide. Thanks a lot
I'd like to center vertically my text, in each slide. Thanks a lot
I'd like to center vertically my text, in each slide. Thanks a lot
\Fill
\end{wideslide}


\begin{slide}{Illustration}\Fill
I'd like to center vertically my text, in each slide. Thanks a lot

I'd like to center vertically my text, in each slide. Thanks a lot
\Fill
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Thanks a lot. It's very friendly. But the text is not centered. For example, f i write one, two, ... paragraph, all the text start always at 0.5\slideheight (not centered, so). Could you find another way ? Best regards,

Comment: @Herbert I have voted your question and I have deleted my answer. +1

Comment: @loruyza: I see. I suppose that the complete frame definition has to be redefined. Will see, what I can do

Comment: @loruyza: see edited answer. However, using `beamer` instead make things easier ...

Comment: Hello It's ok for me. It seems that Powerdot could not adjust directly.  Thanks again. I know Beamer, it was my first try with Powerdot. Best regards